# Connection refused: Identifier rejected with ngx-mqtt and Mosquitto via Websockets

Tags: angular, websocket, mosquitto

I have a Mosquitto broker running from my console on the ports 1883 with the MQTT protocol as well as a websockets connection on port 9001.

```
PS C:\Program Files\mosquitto> .\mosquitto.exe -v -c .\mosquitto.conf
1643212564: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1643212564: Config loaded from .\mosquitto.conf.
1643212564: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1643212564: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1643212564: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1643212564: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
```

I can connect to the MQTT port from MQTT Explorer without issue, but not to the websocket endpoint.

The error I receive from my Angular application that uses `ngx-mqtt` is:

```
ngx-mqtt.js:108 Error: Connection refused: Identifier rejected
    at MqttClient.push../node_modules/
    ngx-mqtt/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js.MqttClient._handleConnack (client.js:1185:1)
```

In my `mosquitto.conf`, I am allowing anonymous connections. I have no idea why the identifier is rejected. I looked into the module and they are created normally.

The mosquitto.conf file contains the following:

```
listener 1883

listener 9001
protocol websockets

allow_anonymous true
```

From the broker side, the clients appear to connect and immediately disconnect:

```
1643212911: New client connected from ::1:59092 as client-99c48hibcas (p2, c1, k0, u'guest').
1643212911: No will message specified.
1643212911: Sending CONNACK to client-99c48hibcas (0, 2)
1643212911: Client client-99c48hibcas closed its connection.
```

I have no idea why this does not work. I cannot connect to the websocket endpoint via Angular's ngx-mqtt or MQTT explorer. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your full mosquitto.conf file. Describing it isn’t helpful; sharing it is. Also have you opened port 9001 on the Windows firewall?

Comment: I will add the file. It only contains the opened listener port at 1883 and the listener at 9001 with the websockets protocol.

The firewall is completely deactivated. Also, would the broker reject the identifier if the firewall was blocking the connection? I think there would be no connection from the client side, right?

Comment: Include the angular code in the question, specifically the bit where the connection is setup, but best guess change the clientid (try something shorter)

Comment: Interesting, I will check this out. The clientid is 18 chars, which according to MQTT standard, is within the limit of 23. But I will report back.

Comment: Apparently, we set "keep alive" to 0, which caused the connections to not work. Setting them to any other value works. Sorry, I didn't know this might be the problem. It was part of the ngx-mqtt configuration. @hardlib